# Symfony4 - Can't get error_mapping to work

Tags: forms, symfony, validation

In my Symfony4 project, I have an entity called 'Customer'. This entity has an extra validation method to do some extra validation for the field 'zip code'. When a zip code is invalid i receive a general error.

```
    /**
    @Assert\IsTrue(message = "invalid.zipcode")
     */
    public function isZipCodeValid()
    {
      ...
      return false;
    }
```

I would like to map this specific error to the 'zip code' field so i can show users which field is causing the issue.

I have tried the following code in the CustomerForm, as mentioned in the Symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-mapping

```
    ....
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Customer::class,
            'error_mapping' => [
                'isZipCodeValid' => 'zip_code',
            ],
        ]);   
    }
```

Unfortunately this keeps sending a global error after posting my form. Not sure why.. Does anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks!

buildForm:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {               
        $builder          
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Name',  'attr' => array('size' => '50')))         
            ->add('address_line', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Addressline', 'attr' => array('size' => '50')))
            ->add('zip_code', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Zipcode', 'attr' => array('size' => '20')))
            ->add('city', TextType::class, array('label' => 'City', 'attr' => array('size' => '50')));
    }
```

Comment: Please show the rest of your form builder code, so we know what fields you've added.

Comment: Hi Will, just added the buildForm code.